# Horizontally scrollable nested itemscontrol

Tags: windows-phone-7

I am developing a windows phone 7 application.
I need to display list of channels vertically. Next to each channel i need to display programs for that particular channel which should be horizontally scrollable. Can any one suggest how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a nested listbox, setting a scrollviewer in the child list, something along this lines should get you started

```
public class Channel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<Program> Programs { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

In your code behind

```
 public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindChannels();
    }

  private void BindChannels()
  {
      lstChannels.ItemsSource = new[]
          {
              new Channel { Name = "BBC 1", Programs = new[] { new Program { Name = "Abbey Town" }, new Program { Name = "Early Bird" }, new Program { Name = "East enders" } } }, 
              new Channel { Name = "BBC 2", Programs = new[] { new Program { Name = "Dancing stars" }, new Program { Name = "David and G" }, new Program { Name = "The Eastern blocks" } } }, 
              new Channel { Name = "ITV", Programs = new[] { new Program { Name = "X Factor" }, new Program { Name = "X Factor reloaded" }, new Program { Name = "The game" } } }, 
              new Channel { Name = "Fox News", Programs = new[] { new Program { Name = "Early news" }, new Program { Name = "Talk C" }, new Program { Name = "Recap" } } }
          };
  }
```

Xaml

```
<ListBox x:Name="lstChannels">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Margin="0,6,0,0" Height="Auto">
                        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Programs}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Margin="12,0,0,0">
                            <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                    <StackPanel Orientation ="Horizontal" >
                                        <StackPanel.RenderTransform>
                                            <TranslateTransform
                                 X="0" />
                                        </StackPanel.RenderTransform>

                                    </StackPanel>
                                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <Border Height="100" Width="200" BorderBrush="Bisque" BorderThickness="3">
                                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                                    </Border>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        </ListBox>
                    </ScrollViewer>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
```